# The folder doesn't showing

Tags: android

```
 gbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            File folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test");
            boolean sucess =true;
            if(!folder.exists())
            {
                sucess=folder.mkdirs();
            }
            if(sucess)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }






        }
    });
```

I have tried this code

My app need a folder and it's need to show in file explorer help me to create public directory

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to know how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
success = folder.mkdirs();
}
if (success) {
// Do something on success
} else {
// Do something else on failure 
}
```

Add this permission in Manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply 

Yes it's showing success toast but I can't locate folder in file explorer

Comment: try with other device.. i checked this now and it creare and show me test folder

Comment: i didnot gave the runtime permissions

Answer (score 0):

Add Permission in Manufest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Write this code

```
 File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/test");
 if(!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
 }
```

Comment: I have used mkdirs instead of mkdir
And gave the permission 

But you&#39;re right it&#39;s showing the toast created when I check into the es file explorer i can&#39;t locate.

Comment: In which device you test?

Comment: UPdate this code ---
File folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test");

Comment: still not created

Comment: can you come on chat

Comment: Yes , sure.i will come

Comment: i have no reputation www.facebook.com/abisukesh

Comment: Have you uses skype?

Comment: If you test in marshmallow version then please add run time permission